# SQL Server SSRS Reporting: display null for zero values in stacked column chart

Tags: reporting-services

[image: stacked bar chart]

I have created a stacked column report in SSRS which is working ok except on few columns when value is null some strange words are displaying.

I don't want to display any value where value is zero

Please help me how to display null in case of zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the value expression, if the value is null, set it to Nothing.

IIF(Field.Value = 0,Nothing,Field.Value)

'Nothing' is compatible with numeric datatypes , but it will generally show as 'blank' value in a cell.

Comment: Hi Wes, After I applied as per your suggestion and it is working perfect. Thanks a lot Cheers

Comment: @Nadeem please accept an answer to resolve your question.